# Recursion in C Programming

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion, static

It would be a mess if we keep using repetitive calling like this :)

```
int fun() 
{
    static int num = 16;
    return num--;
}

int main()
{
    for (fun(); fun(); fun())
    printf("%d ", fun());
    return 0;
}
```

I know the concept of Static but I would like to know how this program works and prints output : `14 11 8 5 2`

Comment: There is no recursion in your program.

Comment: In order for your program to have recursion you need to have a function that calls itself.

Comment: There is no *stack* in C. If we assume an implementation using a *stack* for function calls, it's still uninteresting: there's just one function called repeatedly. Voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking" (but you might want to clarify).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no recursion in your program because there is no function at all that calls itself: neither `func()` calls `func()` nor `main()` calls `main()`.

---

Since the variable `num` in the function `func()` is declared as `static`, all the calls to the function `func()` share a single copy of the variable `num`. This variable is **initialized only once**: the first time the function `func()` gets called. Its value is kept between calls (this variable is not allocated on the stack).

In the following loop:

```
for (fun(); fun(); fun())
   printf("%d ", fun());
```

`func()` is called once at the very beginning and *3 times* on every loop iteration.

Every time `func()` gets called, `num` is decremented by one. For that reason, each time the value returned by `func()` is displayed it is decremented by *three* 
with respect to the last displayed value.